# Add new post redirection

Tags: redirect, homepage

I don't know whats wrong going on with my website, this is the second redirection problem going on,
Whenever I add a new post, After adding title, When I try to add the content, My own websites home-page appears next to the content box, in a red bordered box, and a page tries to load, this page keeps on loading, nothing comes, the url of loading page is "http://mywebsite.com/wp-admin/post-new.php"
[image]

Comment: I thought it was a 'feature' (being able to see a preview of your live site in the admin panel)

Comment: @janoChen its not a joke, I am facing it, and its not a feature

Comment: Sounds like it happens on ajax calls, did you cange server?

Comment: @בניית אתרים nope, for this website I didn't change anything, everything was fine

Comment: The obvious thing to try first would be to disable plugins and re-enable one at a time until the problem is reproduced. This is a "must do" procedure for isolating any WordPress problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [t31os](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/1468/t31os) said, first thing you should do is disable all plugins, see if wp-admin/post-new.php works fine then, and re-enable them one by one, see which one is causing trouble.

I would start with the plugin to change the admin theme, since this is the closest one to the admin dashboard.

Comment: @everyone I figured out the actual reason behind this, sometimes server changes some `mod_security.c` due to which, this was happening, this solution I found on one of the blog
http://nirajmchauhan.blogspot.com/2011/01/wordpress-publish-new-post-redirecting.html

this really worked